# Disable password dialog when opening a password protected Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, passwords, password-protection, excel-interop

I have lots of Excel files protected by some known set of passwords. I would like to **unprotect them all programmatically**.

My problem is that **when I open a file using some wrong password, it shows the password dialog and waits for user input**. *DisplayAlerts = false;* does not work.

How do I **avoid the password dialog box** in case that my password is wrong? Any suggestions?

My current code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

bool TryUnprotectFile(string filePath, string trialPassword)
{
   Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
   excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

   // when password is wrong, then it waits here for user input:
   Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Open(filePath, Password: trialPassword, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended: true, Notify: false);

   // ... further unprotecting code ...

   // should return true when success, false otherwise
}
```

Comment: So you don't have the right password for your excel files ?

Comment: If this is a one-time job, a quick way to help get it done would be to write an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to watch for the dialog and cancel it.